# Parse datetime from CSV, assign timezone and convert to another timezone - Polars Python

Tags: python, datetime, python-polars

I have a column of timestamps in a CSV file, like `2022-01-03 17:59:16.254`. As an external information, I know this time is in JST.

I am trying to parse this string into datetime, assign JST timezone (without changing the timestamp), and convert it to CET.

An attempt:

```
new = pl.scan_csv('test.csv').with_columns(
    [pl.col("timestamp").str.strptime(pl.Datetime, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f", strict=True),
    ]
).select(
    [pl.col("timestamp").cast(pl.Date).alias("Date"),
     pl.col("timestamp").dt.with_time_zone("Asia/Tokyo").alias("WithTZ"),
     pl.col("timestamp").dt.with_time_zone("Asia/Tokyo").dt.cast_time_zone("Europe/Berlin").alias("WithCastTZ"),
     pl.all(),
    ]
)

new.fetch(10).write_csv("testOut.csv")
```

as a result, I was expecting the datetime part to not change in WithTZ. However, this is my first line. Casting also did not have any impact.

```
WithTZ                     |WithCastTZ                 |timestamp
2022-01-04 02:59:16.213 JST|2022-01-04 02:59:16.213 CET|2022-01-03T17:59:16.213000000
```

I think I am missing something obvious..

Comment: I am suspecting that strptime() should know that the source time is in JST. so I tried appending ' JST' to the string and using `%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f %Z` as formatter, but got the exact same result, because 'timestamp' field did not become tz aware after using the new formatter..

Comment: Your example raises an exception for me on polars latest which may help debug: `ComputeError: Cannot call with_time_zone on tz-naive. Set a time zone first with cast_time_zone`

Comment: @jqurious `with_time_zone` should work with naive timestamps, `cast_time_zone` does not. Not sure why you are getting that error.. I am on polars 0.16.2

Comment: It looks like it was added in https://github.com/pola-rs/polars/commit/0cfc7fda9cc149d0bc13df330418727a6de9608a and will be in `0.16.3` (I'm using the latest commit from github) - It seems the timezone stuff is being heavily worked on at the moment - so there are some frequent changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The methods for dealing with time zones are:

- `dt.convert_time_zone`: convert from one time zone to another;
- `dt.replace_time_zone`: set/unset/change time zone;

So here, it sounds like you're after the latter:

```
pl.col("timestamp").dt.replace_time_zone("Asia/Tokyo")
```

To then convert to Europe/Berlin:

```
pl.col("timestamp").dt.replace_time_zone("Asia/Tokyo").dt.convert_time_zone("Europe/Berlin")
```

Comment: Of course. Coming from Pandas, I should have known.. FWIW, Polars API guide does not mention tz_localize... I was only able to discover it via browsing the ExprDateTimeNameSpace class in the Python module.

Comment: You're right, looks like not everything is in the user guide. Looks like this might be changing BTW: https://github.com/pola-rs/polars/issues/6767

Comment: updated as per polars 0.16.3